# multiprocessing queue not joining

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I am using multiprocessing (and [pebble](https://pythonhosted.org/Pebble/#pebble-module)) to create one or more producer processes and one or more consumer processes. The producer adds items to a queue, the consumers pull from the queue and then call `task_done`. My main function calls the queue's `join()`function which should block until

> all items have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for every item that had been put() into the queue)

However, the join blocks forever even though `task_done` has been called for each item put on the queue. See example below:

```
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import pebble
import queue
import time    

def add_to_queue(num, q):
    # add num to the queue `q`
    time.sleep(2) # pretend i'm doing work
    print("putting on queue")
    q.put(num)
    print("put on queue done")
    return num    

def worker(q, output, done):
    # continually pull items off the queue until the done event is set
    while True:
        if done.set():
            return
        try:
            print("Getting from queue")
            num = q.get(block=True, timeout=10)
            print("Got from queue")
        except queue.Empty:
            print("EMPTY QUEUE")
            # If i add this it errors saying "called to many times"
            # q.task_done() 
            continue
        time.sleep(num)
        output.append(num)
        # mark item as processed
        q.task_done()
        print("task done")    

def main(n_checkers=1):
    mgr = mp.Manager()
    q = mgr.Queue()
    output = mgr.list()
    done = mgr.Event()
    workers = []    

    add_partial = partial(add_to_queue, q=q)
    with pebble.ProcessPool(n_checkers) as pool:
        nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        map_future = pool.map(add_partial, nums)
        for i in range(n_checkers):
            print("SCHEDULING WORKER", i)
            ftr = pool.schedule(worker, args=(q, output, done))
            workers.append(ftr)
    
        for r in map_future.result():
            print(r)
    
        print("Joining Queue")
        # NEVER Joins even though we've called `task_done` for each input in `nums`
        q.join()
        done.set()
        for w in workers:
            w.result()
        
    print(output)
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in function `worker` where you are calling `done.set` instead of `done.is_set()`:

```py
def worker(q, output, done):
    # continually pull items off the queue until the done event is set
    while True:
        #if done.set(): # oops!
        if done.is_set():
```

But if I may make a comment and offer a suggestion.

First the comment:

Why are you mixing a multiprocessing pool, which uses a `multiprocessing.Queue` or similar structure (I am not familiar with `pebble`) underneath for passing tasks consisting of worker functions and its arguments to the pool processes, with a managed queue for passing work to your worker function? I would be using an explicit queue only if I were implementing my own processing pool using, for example, `multiprocessing.Process` instances.

Now the suggestion:

But if you insist, the processing can be greatly simplified by placing on the input queue special "end of file" records, one for each checker, that signals to the checker that there will be no more records being placed on the queue and that the checker may now terminate. This removes the need for a `done` event and for having a timeout for the `queue.get()` call. The "end of file" record just needs to be something that is distinguishable from a "normal" record. In this case `None` serves the purpose perfectly. Since I am not familiar with `pebble`, this has been tested with the `multiprocessing.Pool` class. The untested `pebble` version follows:

**`multiprocessing.Pool` Version**

```py
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import time

def add_to_queue(num, q):
    # add num to the queue `q`
    time.sleep(2) # pretend i'm doing work
    print("putting on queue")
    q.put(num)
    print("put on queue done")
    return num

def worker(q, output):
    # continually pull items off the queue until end of file:
    while True:
        print("Getting from queue")
        num = q.get(block=True)
        if num is None:
            q.task_done()
            print("task done")
            break # end of file
        print("Got from queue")
        time.sleep(num)
        output.append(num)
        # mark item as processed
        q.task_done()
        print("task done")

def main(n_checkers=1):
    mgr = mp.Manager()
    q = mgr.Queue()
    output = mgr.list()
    workers = []

    add_partial = partial(add_to_queue, q=q)
    with mp.Pool(n_checkers) as pool:
        nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        # add end of file indicators, one per checker:
        nums += [None] * n_checkers
        map_result = pool.map_async(add_partial, nums)
        for i in range(n_checkers):
            print("SCHEDULING WORKER", i)
            ftr = pool.apply_async(worker, args=(q, output))
            workers.append(ftr)

        for r in map_result.get():
            print(r)

        print("Joining Queue")
        # NEVER Joins even though we've called `task_done` for each input in `nums`
        q.join()
        for w in workers:
            w.get()

    print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**`pebble` Version**

```py
from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
import pebble
import queue
import time    

def add_to_queue(num, q):
    # add num to the queue `q`
    time.sleep(2) # pretend i'm doing work
    print("putting on queue")
    q.put(num)
    print("put on queue done")
    return num    

def worker(q, output):
    # continually pull items off the queue until end of file:
    while True:
        print("Getting from queue")
        num = q.get()
        if num is None: # end of file record
            q.task_done()
            print("task done")
            break
        print("Got from queue")
        time.sleep(num)
        output.append(num)
        # mark item as processed
        q.task_done()
        print("task done")    

def main(n_checkers=1):
    mgr = mp.Manager()
    q = mgr.Queue()
    output = mgr.list()
    workers = []    

    add_partial = partial(add_to_queue, q=q)
    with pebble.ProcessPool(n_checkers) as pool:
        nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        # add end of file records, one for each checker:
        nums += [None] * n_checkers
        map_future = pool.map(add_partial, nums)
        for i in range(n_checkers):
            print("SCHEDULING WORKER", i)
            ftr = pool.schedule(worker, args=(q, output))
            workers.append(ftr)
    
        for r in map_future.result():
            print(r)
    
        print("Joining Queue")
        q.join()
        for w in workers:
            w.result()
        
    print(output)
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, the done.set was a typo and my issue turned out to be something else (equally stupid), but thank you for the advice i've changed my script to follow it!